# R - convert date column in daily format to hourly granularity

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
> head(df)
        date    demand
1 2019-09-21    6
2 2019-09-21    1
3 2019-09-21    9
4 2019-09-21    3
5 2019-09-21    12
6 2019-09-21    3
```

and I will like it to have hourly granularity as follows:

```
> head(df)
                 date   demand
1 2019-09-21 00:00:00   6
2 2019-09-21 01:00:00   1
3 2019-09-21 02:00:00   9
4 2019-09-21 03:00:00   3
5 2019-09-21 04:00:00   12
6 2019-09-21 05:00:00   3
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently in R? The closest answer I've found is [R Programming: Create hourly time intervals in an array with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618386/r-programming-create-hourly-time-intervals-in-an-array-with-for-loop) and [Matching and Replacing values of a column in a dataframe by date in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216200/matching-and-replacing-values-of-a-column-in-a-dataframe-by-date-in-r) but I can't seem implement them for my problem.. Some insights will be deeply appreciated!

**Remark**: There are multiple days in the dataframe, each day contains 24 hours of daates as above in `df`. The first date should have hour starting at 12am (00:00:00) and the last date has hour at 11pm (23:00:00).

Comment: Are there multiple days in your `df` dataset? If so, it might be a good idea to show a representative example with multiple days as the answer will change a fair bit depending on that.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, thanks or raising that up. I'll add it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, something like this would help :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(date) + 3600 * 0:(n() - 1))
  #We can also use another variation suggested by @thelatemail
  #mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(date) + as.difftime(seq_len(n())-1, unit="hours")) 

#  date       demand datetime           
#  <fct>       <int> <dttm>             
#1 2019-09-21      6 2019-09-21 00:00:00
#2 2019-09-21      1 2019-09-21 01:00:00
#3 2019-09-21      9 2019-09-21 02:00:00
#4 2019-09-21      3 2019-09-21 03:00:00
#5 2019-09-21     12 2019-09-21 04:00:00
#6 2019-09-21      3 2019-09-21 05:00:00
```

This can also be written in base R :

```
df$datetime <- with(df, ave(as.POSIXct(date), date, 
                    FUN = function(x) x + 3600 * 0:(length(x) - 1)))
```

Comment: Variation - `mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(date) + as.difftime(seq_len(n())-1, unit="hours"))` - I like to make the hours explicit.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak and @thelatemail! It works, just that @thelatemail, for your I got the error: `Error in seq_len(n() - 1, units="hours") : 2 arguments passed to 'seq_len' which requires 1`.

Comment: @Stoner - you haven't copied the code exactly by the looks of your error message - compare `as.difftime(seq_len(n())-1, unit="hours"))` and `as.difftime(seq_len(n() - 1, units="hours")`